# How do I install the .jar mod called Forge for Minecraft 1.7.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

After some errors with using the actual windows installer,I have gone to using the regular one.However,I'm not sure how exactly to install it.The name is:  forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180-installer-win .So,does anyone know how to install this?

Answer (score 2):

Double click on the icon - the installer should launch and automatically install to your Minecraft installation. This only works with this specific mod - you can see in the file name **installer** appears.

Answer (score 0):

You should right click on the actual .jar. Do you see Open With? Hover over that option, and look for the java option. Just click that!

Comment: Who did that and why?

Comment: More detailed instructions maybe benefit you.